# Inserting image title into database not working?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, So I came up with a way to upload images on my forum website, by having a check in the database, and having the image title inserted into the database as well. When I display the image, it checks to see if the check is true, and if it is, it echoes an html tag with the image name. My problem is with uploading the image title into the database. It doesn't insert into the database. Can you please help?

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once 'dbh.php';


$forum = $_SESSION['forum'];
$name = $_SESSION['username'];
$check = "true";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$file = $_FILES['file'];

$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

$fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

$allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf', 'gif', 'bmp', 'mp4', 'avi',);

if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
    if ($fileError === 0) {
    if ($fileSize < 1000000000) {
        $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true) . "." . $fileActualExt;
        $fileDestination = "uploads/" . $fileNameNew;
        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO $forum (name, post, image) VALUES ('$name', '$fileName', '$check');";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        header("Location: display.php?success");
    } else {
        echo "your file is too big";
    }
    } else {
    echo "there was an error";
    }
} else {
    echo "you cannot upload this type of file!";
}
```

}

Comment: Check what `$result` is before saying `success`. Check for errors. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php You also are open to SQL injections, parameterize.

Comment: @user3783243 how do I do that. I tried to echo the variable after the insert is supposed to happen but I get literally no output. What now?

Comment: You can't echo a boolean, try `var_dump($result);` and use the error reporting function I linked

Comment: @user3783243 I don't know what I'm looking for. I'm really not very fluent in the PHP syntax. The link doesn't have anything I understand in it

Comment: You need to learn how to read those links. That is the manual and tells you everything you need to know. Put the `mysqli_query` in a conditional and add `printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));`   inside. Look at the `Procedural style` of example 1 on the link.

Comment: @user3783243 I don't even know what that means. I'm more confused now. I've used the same script countless times, with absolutely no error, and If I knew how to read those manuals, I would have already, but i'm new and have no Idea what I'm doing. It's obvious you know what to do better than I do, so if you could point me somewhere where I would be able to process this in bite sizes, I would appreciate that

Comment: I don't know of anything like that, the manual is what I learned from and what I use. Take a look at https://pastebin.com/k8ypyv7P. Also why is the table name stored in the session, that seems like a bad idea. The manual has 4 sections `Description` which tells what the function does. `Parameters` which are what it takes/expects. `Return Values` which is what the function gives back. And then `Examples` which show the exact usage.

Answer (score -1):

First change $fileName to $fileNameNew in your $sql string

then also change your query line to this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

now the response from the post request should have the error.

Comment: That would result in the wrong file being linked, not in the query not executing.

Comment: It still doesn't work. The problem is,the SQL won't insert the name into the database. Every time I try it, nothing show's up in the table

Comment: Yes maybe but also maybe it is executing and the image not visible when retrieved due to wrong name and  he assumes it is not inserted.

Comment: can you post your html  form code? are you using multipart?

Comment: @AmrBerag I can see the phpmyadmin table... It's not inserting. My html code isn't the problem. The image is put into it's folder like it supposed to with a unique ID, the problem is with the code that inserts the names into the database

Comment: You can find the errors using firefox developer tools.You need to access the respons to your post request and its headers. refer to my last comment to the question

Comment: also change your query line to this: $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));